# Jquery, jCrumb configuration

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have decided to try out the jQuery plugin 'jCrumb'. What i am a little stuck with is how to add my own image as a separator and how to control the name of the breadcrumb it generates.

So I downloaded jCrumb from  http://www.somethinghitme.com/projects/jCrumb/index.html?t=JCrumb%20Page%203

and you can pass options through a function

```
(function($){
 $.fn.jCrumb = function(options) {
 var settings = {
    maxCrumbs : 4,
    maxMemory : 15,
    defaultClass : 'jCrumb',
    jqUI : false,
    seperator : "&gt;"
  },
```

the breadcrumbs work ok, as in it follows my navigation, but rather than show the breadcrumbs as this for example

```
Home / News / Contact
```

they show like this

```
Nameofmysite | Home > nameofmysite | News > nameofmysite | Contact Us
```

Where is the plugin getting the info from and how would i change it to just

```
Home / News / Contact Us
```

edit

The title is taken from this method

```
 def title
 base_title = "Newbridges"
 if @title.nil?
  base_title
 else
  "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
 end
 end
```

How would i get the plugin to ignore the base title?

Edit

The title is set using this section in the plugin

```
  setCrumb(document.title + '^' +  window.location.href);

  var crumbs = getCrumbs(),
    crumbVal = "",
    crumbList =  $(document.createElement('ul')).addClass(settings.defaultClass).appendTo($(this)),
    crumbListItem = "";

  if(settings.jqUI){
    crumbList.addClass('fg-buttonset fg-buttonset-single ui-helper-clearfix');
  }

  if(crumbs){
    crumbs = crumbs.split('*');
    startIndex = 0;
```

I am developing the site in rails, not sure if that makes a difference to any option i have

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `document.title` is hardcoded into the jCrumb plugin, which means it will take whatever is set by Rails.

So you have two options:

Either change your `title` method in Rails so it does not prepend the site name to the document title:

```
def title
  base_title = "Newbridges"
  if @title.nil?
   base_title
  else
   @title
  end
end
```

...or extend or modify the jCrumb plugin so that instead of `document.title` it uses `document.title.split(" | ")[1]`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i think i will go for modifying the plugin, i have updated my question to show where document.title is being set, do i modify the first line or the split where crumbs.split is being used